# IEC 61000-3-3 flicker for switches and relays

Tags: emc, standard, iec

IEC 61000-3-3 shall be used for testing all 230V 50Hz AC devices with up to 16A current rating.

What about switches, relays, power plugs-basically devices that act as gateways between mains and actual load? From my understanding these type of devices shall be excluded from that particular test because they just act as “piece of cable with a mechanical switch”. It is the actual load that impacts the flicker. When talking with compliance testing labs, they tend to want to apply 61000-3-3 tests to everything that is plugged into the mains. Any advice on this topic?